# Wind an electric car window down?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

The phrase originates from car windows which used to have manual handles, which need to be turned to lower the window, hence to 'wind' a window down.

I heard the phrase the other day, but the car in question had electric windows. Is it OK to say we 'wind down' electric windows, or is there a newer phrase?

Comment: Anything is okay if it gets the message across! :) But, yeah, to say "wind" when there is no crank seems out of place. So, I agree with @user3169 about using some alternative verbs in this situation. Or even: *Could you put my window up--the wind is blowing in too much and messing up my hair?*

Comment: And here I thought you were going to ask about "*an electric car's window*" vs "*an electric car window*" vs "*the window of an electric car*" vs "*power windows*"

Comment: i've managed to come up with 'slide'

Comment: Don't you still *hang up* the phone? These things are fairly common in most languages - perhaps you can think of an example in your native tongue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "wind" in this case. There are plenty of situations where we use a word that refers to an obsolete technology:

- we *dial* a phone number, which makes the other person's phone *ring*; we *hang up* at the end of the call;
- we listen to internet *radio stations* (though I suppose that's almost correct, if you're using wifi);
- we *carbon copy* emails;
- diesel-powered ships *sail* around the world.

Comment: not sure if this is the same thing, but aeroplanes still 'take off'?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry That doesn't seem to be the same thing: what obsolete technology does that refer to? (E.g., "dial a phone number" refers to telephones using a rotary dial before they had keypads.)

Comment: this is not quite an answer to my question - I wanted an alternative word to describe the action of opening/closing an electric window other than wind/roll up/down, but the points made are interesting.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry "Is it OK to say we 'wind down' electric windows, or is there a newer phrase?" Yes, it is OK to say we 'wind down' electric windows.

Comment: We do still "wind down" car windows, even when they're electric - we just use a (hidden) motor to help with the winding :-)

Comment: For another example of obsolete usage persisting, we _turn_ lights on and off, or shut them off: from the gas light era where there was a valve controlling the flow of gas. IIRC other languages also talk about opening and closing lights in their own idioms.

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I still say, "Roll down your window," even though I have never owned a car with manual windows. That is the phrase I always used growing up, so I still use it now. (I am 28).
Everyone knows what I mean, and I don't think it sounds strange.
Technically, there is a motor inside the car that is spinning and rolling the windows down, even if you are just pushing a button, right?

I live in the Midwest, but people in other parts of America may say "wind down", instead of "roll down".

If you wanted to use another phrase, I would go with "open" and "close".

Comment: My impression is that *roll down* is the usual phrase in American English and *wind down* is British.

Comment: I've lived from California to Maine. AFAIK, "roll up/down" is standard in the US.

Comment: +1: "Roll down" is the idiomatic way (AmE) to talk about lowering a car's window, and it simply doesn't matter that it's no longer literal. See also: "rewind" to go back to an earlier point in a movie on DVD, "hang up" the phone,  anything that you "turn on", "turn down" the volume...

Comment: ... "write" an email, type or even worse dictate a "manuscript", perhaps arguably "drive" a car (literally-speaking you *drive* the horses, and they pull the carriage, but it's called driving a carriage by an obvious figurative connection). On my stereo I can still literally "turn down" the volume, it's a rotating analogue control, but I can also push a button on the remote and a motor turns it for me, much like the window :-)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I was responding to a now-deleted comment that seemed to be suggesting that English is only spoken in the USA.

Answer (score 6):

I would use:

> Would you **raise/lower** your window?

or simply:

> Would you **close/open** your window?

Since you can't see how the mechanism operates, you should just use visual observation terms.

Comment: I should use whatever I want to use, as long as my listener or reader will understand. :|

Answer (score 3):

You can also say:

> Would you **put** your window down/up?

Comment: That gets the message across but it doesn't sound very natural to me (British native speaker).

Comment: Definitely a US thing.

Comment: @Zimul8r not at all a US thing! No one I know says that, nor do I hear it in the popular media. Americans mostly say "roll up/down" or "open/close".

Answer (score 0):

I think to say " turn the window down or up" as of turning your signal on or off would go with electric windows as you are in a same way turning a switch on or off. Both winding or Rolling do refer to windows with manual cranking handles.